# Trees in CouchDB

Tags: tree, couchdb

I'm new to CouchDB and have a question.

I'm saving messages with the ID of the parent message as an attribute.
A message can also have a childMessage as parent, so it looks like a tree.

How can i query all childs including the childs of the childs?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the commonly used method when dealing with hierarchical data: http://probablyprogramming.com/2008/07/04/storing-hierarchical-data-in-couchdb/

Comment: Is this really the best practice for trees? It is very bad when moving nodes, as the author acknowledges just before the Conclusion paragraph.

Answer (score -1):

CouchDB works best with the de-normalized data. You should consider de-normalizing your data as much as possible. Maybe you may store the whole tree as a single document?

E.g.:

```
{
  "msg":"Parent message",
  "children":[
    {
       "msg":"sub message 1"
    },
    {
       "msg":"sub message 2",
       "children":[
         {
           "msg":"sub sub message 1"
         }
       ]
    }
  ]
}
```